# iText direct Printing

Tags: java, pdf, printing, itext

I am using iText  to generate a pdf and write it to the file system as the following:

```
private void createPDF() throws Exception{
    com.itextpdf.text.Document doc = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
    PdfWriter docWriter = null;
    path = "C:\\PATH\\TO\\Desktop\\EXAMPLE_FOLDER\\" + pdfFilename;
    docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(path));
    doc.addTitle("Invoice");
    doc.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
    doc.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();
    fillPDFDetails(cb);
    if (doc != null) {
        doc.close();
    }
    if (docWriter != null) {
        docWriter.close();
    }
}
```

However, I want to send the pdf to the printer and print the pdf file instead of writing it to the file system. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "Printing PDF files from java" - https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a theoretical and a practical answer to this question.

Let's start with the theoretical answer. There's a Java class called [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) that allows you to send an `OutputStream` to a printer:

> `Printstream` extends `FilterOutputStream` extends `OutputStream`
>
> A `PrintStream` adds functionality to another output stream, namely the
>   ability to print representations of various data values conveniently.
>   Two other features are provided as well. Unlike other output streams,
>   a `PrintStream` never throws an `IOException`; instead, exceptional
>   situations merely set an internal flag that can be tested via the
>   `checkError` method. Optionally, a `PrintStream` can be created so as to
>   flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically
>   invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is
>   invoked, or a newline character or byte (`'\n'`) is written.

So, suppose that you would like to create a PDF in memory and write it to a printer, you'd do something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, ps);
document.open();
// add content
document.close();
```

As `PrintStream` extends `OutputStream` and as `PdfWriter` accepts any type of `OutputStream`, you are writing the PDF bytes to the printer and if you want the PDF bytes, you can do `baos.toByteArray()`.

However, the code snippet above sends PDF bytes to the printer. Chances are that your printer doesn't understand PDF and just prints out stuff like:

```
PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
2 0 obj
<</Length 64/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
*binary stuff*
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Parent 3 0 R/Contents 2 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</Font<</F1 1 0 R>>>>
/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[4 0 R]>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 3 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Producer(iText® 5.4.2 ©2000-2012 1T3XT BVBA \(AGPL-version\))
/ModDate(D:20130502165150+02'00')/CreationDate(D:20130502165150+02'00')>>
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000302 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000390 00000 n 
0000000145 00000 n 
0000000441 00000 n 
0000000486 00000 n 
trailer
<</Root 5 0 R/ID [<91bee3a87061eb2834fb6a3258bf817e><91bee3a87061eb2834fb6a3258bf817e>]
/Info 6 0 R/Size 7>>
%iText-5.4.2
startxref
639
%%EOF
```

**Update:**

In a comment, the following link was added: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/

This is actually a better way to print your file:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(“C:/mypdf.pdf”);
Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, null, null);
DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
fis.close();
```

If you don't want to use a `FileInputStream`, you can always create the PDF as a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and use the resulting `byte[]` to create a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

That's what the practical answer is about: it's not that difficult to create a PDF in memory. That's done like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
// add content
document.close();
byte[] pdf = baos.toByteArray();
```

The question is: what are you going to do with `pdf`?

Either your printer understands those bytes (there are printers that accept PDF syntax), or you'll have to find software that converts PDF into a format that printers understand. Usually, people use PDF rendering software (such as Adobe Reader) to print a document. Many of these viewers (Adobe Reader is one of them), require the file to exist as a file: Adobe Reader does not accept a byte array.

This explains why the practical answer isn't as easy as the theoretical answer: in practice, your question is far from trivial: it depends on the printer (which formats does it accept) and the PDF viewer (should you require one).

Comment: I have implemented your code, I'm getting the java.io.IOException: The document has no pages Exception.

Comment: That's because you didn't add anything where it says `// add content`.

Comment: I'm adding the details there!

Comment: The exception tells me that you aren't adding anything to the `Document` instance. So whatever the details are, it's not content.

Comment: I used the same code to write the file into the file system and it was working properly. Can you please see the complete code here? http://www.codeshare.io/tFXNL

Comment: Well, the exception is clear: it is only thrown if you're not adding any actual content.

Comment: I have researched and found that adding document.add(new Chunk(""));  will solve the problem. Then after that nothing happens! How would I know that the job was sent to the printer? Nothing appears and even windows print dialog is not appearing

Comment: The process sets an internal flag that can be tested via the `checkError` method. My bet is that the printer doesn't accept PDF.

Comment: But I can print any pdf file successfully with the connected printer! It appears that the printing job is not invoked

Comment: Maybe you can print any PDF successfully from an application such as Adobe Reader, but that doesn't mean you can print that PDF from Java!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So based on your answer, it is not possible to print a pdf file from Java memory because this would mean that a pdf processor such as Adobe Reader would need to access Java memory which is impossible. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. If your printer *understands PDF*, you can print directly to a printer (but many printers *don't understand PDF*). It *may* be possible with a PDF rendering library such as https://www.idrsolutions.com/pdf-print-quick-start/ (you'd have to ask the people of IDR Solutions of JPedal accepts a `byte[]` instead of a path to a PDF file).

Comment: I see. I think I need to find a better way of doing it then! Thanks anyways! I will accept your answer

Comment: @fareed did you find a way? i also need to print an in memory pdf

Comment: @SibiJohn yes, you can send the pdf to the printing service and it will print.

Comment: @fareed in my case the printer is not able to understand the PDF byte syntax. i was hoping you had found a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
filename = "aaaaaaa.pdf";
java.io.File fileout =  new File(filename);
com.lowagie.tools.Executable.printDocumentSilent(fileout));
 fileout.delete();  // if you don't want to keep it.
```

Answer (score -1):

Using APACHE PDFBox (1.x): https://pdfbox.apache.org

Full code: https://github.com/marcolopes/dma/blob/master/org.dma.java/src/org/dma/java/awt/PrinterHandler.java

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterAbortException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class PrinterHandler {

    public static PrintService lookupPrintService(String printerName) {
        for(PrintService ps: PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices()) {
            if (ps.getName().indexOf(printerName)>=0) return ps;
        }return null;
    }

    private final PrintService service;

    private final String printerName;

    public PrinterHandler(String printerName) {
        this.printerName=printerName;
        this.service=lookupPrintService(printerName);
    }


    public void checkPrinter() throws PrinterException {
        if (service==null) throw new PrinterException("Invalid printer "+printerName);
    }


    public PrinterJob createPrinterJob() throws PrinterException {

        checkPrinter();

        PrinterJob job=PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintService(service);
        return job;

    }


    /** Prints a PDF using apache pdfbox */
    public void printPdf(File file) throws PrinterException, PrintException {

        PrinterJob job=createPrinterJob();

        if (file!=null) try{

            job.setJobName(file.getName());

            PDDocument doc=PDDocument.load(file);

            try{doc.silentPrint(job);
            }catch(PrinterAbortException e){
                 //avoid abort exception
            }catch(PrinterException e){
                throw new PrinterException("Error while printing");
            }finally{
                doc.close();
            }

        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new PrintException("Error loading file "+file);
        }

    }

}
```