# c# Printing a PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext

I have a problem with printing a pdf.
So my Document is being created by writing some values in a pdf document and saving it

```
public void CreateDocument(string name)
    {

        string oldreport = @"..\Resources\FehlerReport.pdf";
        string newreportpath = @"..\Resources\" + name;
        using (var newFileStream = new FileStream(newreportpath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(oldreport);

            var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream);

            var form = stamper.AcroFields;

            var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

            form.SetField("Auftragsnummer", Kundeninformation.Auftragsnummer.ToString());
            form.SetField("Kundensachnummer", Kundeninformation.Kundensachnummer.ToString());
            form.SetField("Kundenname", Kundeninformation.Kundenname.ToString());
            form.SetField("Kundenbestellnummer", Kundeninformation.Kundenbestellnummer.ToString());
            form.SetField("Kundenrezepturnummer", Kundeninformation.Kundenrezepturnummer.ToString());
            form.SetField("Spulennummer", Kundeninformation.Spulennummer.ToString());

            form.SetField("Fertigungsdatum1", System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yy"));

            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in _MeasurementReport.MeasurementReportItems)
            {
                form.SetField(("UhrzeitRow" + i).ToString(), item.Uhrzeit.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                form.SetField(("FehlerindexRow" + i).ToString(), i.ToString());
                form.SetField(("Position mmRow" + i).ToString(), (item.Laufmeter * pixelSize).ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                form.SetField(("HoeheRow" + i).ToString(), (item.DefectCountours.H * pixelSize).ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                form.SetField(("Breite mmRow" + i).ToString(), (item.DefectCountours.W * pixelSize).ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                form.SetField(("Flaeche Row" + i).ToString(), (item.DefectCountours.W * pixelSize * pixelSize).ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                i++;
            }

            form.SetField("Datum", System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yy"));
            form.SetField("Uhrzeit", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));

            stamper.FormFlattening = true;


            stamper.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
        }

    }
```

So now i want to print the document with this function, which also calls the CreateDocument function. It prints, but the paper is white. I checked if the created pdf is being created, and it is being created but apparently not printed.

```
    public void Print()
        {

            string name = Kundeninformation.Auftragsnummer + "_" + Kundeninformation.Spulennummer+".pdf";
            CreateDocument(name);
            List<string> PrinterFound = new List<string>();
            PrinterSettings printer = new PrinterSettings();
            foreach (var item in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            {
                PrinterFound.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            printer.PrinterName = PrinterFound[7];
            printer.PrintFileName = name;

            PrintDocument PrintDoc = new PrintDocument();

            PrintDoc.DocumentName = @"..\Resources\"+name;
            PrintDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterFound[7];

            PrintDoc.Print();
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are successfully creating a PDF, right? You've verified and manually printed it with a program such as Adobe Acrobat or Reader. I ask because if we're good there then we can focus solely on your printing issue and ignore the PDF generation part.

Comment: Well it's created right on my laptop but apparently it's not created right remotely on a different pc..don't know what's going on there too. but focusing on the printing problem would be fine

Comment: Have you read this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755305/itext-direct-printing  (for java)

Answer (score 1):

make sure your file is created completely.. otherwise you will this issue. to test quickly put some delay between file creation and printing